# Why the final accuracy is far different to the one showing

Tags: model, tflearn

I run a simple Neural network for training. The input is 12 features and output is 25. I run the code by using tflearn, but as the screenshot shows, why is the final accuracy not around 0.68?

[image]

my code is :

```
    #Set network variables and hyperparameters
    nIn = 12
    nHidden = 200
    nOut = 25
    alpha = 0.01
    nEpochs = 500
    testSplit = 0.2
    batchSize = 32

    input_layer = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, nIn])
    layer2 = tflearn.fully_connected(input_layer, nHidden, activation="relu")
    out = tflearn.fully_connected(layer2, nOut, activation="softmax")

    #sgd = tflearn.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001, lr_decay=0.0, decay_step=1000, staircase=False, use_locking=False)
    network = tflearn.regression(out, optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy",batch_size=batchSize)

    model = tflearn.DNN(network)

    #Number of data points used for testing
    num_test = int(testSplit * len(data))

    #Split data into train and  test
    trainX = dataX[:-num_test]
    testX = dataX[-num_test:]

    trainY = dataY[:-num_test]
    testY = dataY[-num_test:]

    model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=nEpochs, show_metric=True)

    print("Final Accuracy:", model.evaluate(testX, testY))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your code, you see that you calculate the accuracy of your model using your validation set. This means: your model never see that data until this point.

When you train a network on your training data, it reuses the same data for many iterations. In your case, it uses your whole training set at least 499 times and adjusted it's parameters to it. When you use your validation set, it never has seen that data and will perform worse than on your training data. This is absolutely common.

What I'd suggest you to do is, to validate your model during training using your validation data. A common problem that can cause a large gap between training and testing accuracy is the so called `overfit`. This means your models parameters has adjusted too much to the training data and is not able to generalize well to new data. You'll be able to detect such thing by comparing the validation/test accuracy to the training accuracy. If first increases while the second decreases, you'll have an overfit.

Comment: Did this answer your question?